# How to read the response of a signal emitted from a different thread?

Tags: c++, qt

---

`response` print `0` instead of `999`. What the proper way to read the response of the signal in this example?

```cpp
class Worker : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    
    Worker() 
    {
        connect(this, &Worker::signalTest, this, [this] (int x)
        {
            this->Test(x);
        });
    };

    int Test(int x)
    {
      qDebug() << "x: " << x;
      return 999;
    }

public slots:

signals:
    int signalTest(int x);
};
```

---

```cpp
    QThread* thread = new QThread();
    Worker* worker = new Worker();
    worker->moveToThread(thread);
    
    thread->start(); 

    int response = emit worker->signalTest(10);
    qDebug() << "response: " << response;
```

Comment: Consider this: signal can go to any number of slots, using different connection types. Which slot do you expect to determine the return value? Answer: signals are one-way, there's no return value. If you need return value you need to use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`.

Comment: @hyde could you give an example please? would help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to read how to use signals slots correctly in Qt. You need to write a slot that accepts int response as input. And connect the signal to this slot with the QueuedConnection flag

Documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/signalsandslots.html

```
class Worker : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    
    Worker() 
    {
        connect(this, &Worker::signalTest, this, [this] (int x)
        {
            this->Test(x);
        });
    };

    int Test(int x)
    {
      qDebug() << "x: " << x;
      emit signalResp(999);
    }

public slots:
    void slotResp(int x)
    {
       qDebug() << "responce" << x;
    }
signals:
    int signalTest(int x);
    void signalResp(int x);
};
```

---

```
    QThread* thread = new QThread();
    Worker* worker = new Worker();
    worker->moveToThread(thread);
    
    connect(worker, SIGNAL(signalResp(int), worker, SLOT(slotResp(int)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
        
    thread->start(); 

    emit worker->signalTest(10);
```